# Accordion active bar with checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have created the following accordion in jquery:

But I need to add a check box into the accordionButton but I don't want the hidden panel slide down when I click on the the checkbox.

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/NU7Gp/4/

how can I stop the click on the checkbox from firing the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the events [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent events from bubbling up

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NU7Gp/5/